# Multiple commands error in target React-Core-AccessibilityResources

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am getting this below error while trying to make archive version of react native based iOS app.

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/fullmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sagaMobile-fsbtaprxtybkwmagqfnlburrxrfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sagaMobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle':
1) Target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/fullmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sagaMobile-fsbtaprxtybkwmagqfnlburrxrfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sagaMobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
2) Target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/fullmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sagaMobile-fsbtaprxtybkwmagqfnlburrxrfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sagaMobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
```

What I have tried to far is:

```
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod install



if target.name == "React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
      if target.name == "React-Core-AccessibilityResources"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
```

Nothing worked. Please help me to solve

Comment: did you manage to fix this error ? I'm getting the same exact thing

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the "React-Core-AccessibilityResources" (not "React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources").

Comment: no ... :( just breaking head